# Adding Button in a class-iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

I have created one class and named as sample with super class of `UIview`.
Now i want to  add  `UIButton` and `UITextfield`  in my class,and i have created dynamically but its not working.Please check the below code.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{

    UIButton *but=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    but.frame= CGRectMake(200, 15, 15, 15);
    [but setTitle:@"Ok" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [but addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction)    
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:but];
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {
        // Initialization code
     }
    return self;
}
```

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: You should add button after initializing the class object. You can put your button adding code right below "// Initialization code" line. You can also add button in viewDidLoad: method instead of init.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write this code here delete what you done and made change like this..

```
if (self) 
    {
    UIButton *but=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        but.frame= CGRectMake(200, 15, 15, 15);
        [but setTitle:@"Ok" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [but addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction)    
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside;
        [self.view addSubview:but];
     }
    return self;
```

also write this cocde in viewDidLaod() method.

Comment: i wrote inside if(self) only but showing error in the above line i mentioned..ERROR-property view not found on the  object of type

Comment: I think you mean [self addSubview:but] instead of [self.view addSubview:but]. This custom class is a subclass of UIView. The "self"  here already means the object is of type "UIView".

Comment: @Zhang:thanks.Working fine :) And now the situation is i want to place four buttons around one image like top down left right.how to find the  exact location in view ?

Comment: I assume you know the width and height of the image and the buttons. In that case, you can simply subtract the width/height of the buttons + half the width/height of your image to get the coordinates you need.

Comment: @user2791408 ok, thanks. I thought not calling super first caused the problem.

Comment: @zhang:I m not able to add the code for moving to nextview by clicking the above button why is it so?not able to add the above line  [self presentViewController:nexteye animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: I think because [self presentViewController:animated:completion:] method is a UIViewController method but here, your custom class is a subclass of UIView, so it doesn't know about it. You might want to somehow notify your UIViewController in which you plan to add this custom subview to, either through protocol delegate or posting notification using NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: @Zhang:Let me check it.Thanks buddy